# ReflectionException: Class login\Http\Kernel does not exist

Tags: laravel

After Running this command `php artisan app:name Login` My app gives me following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException:  Class login\Http\Kernel
>   does not exist in
>   /home/vagrant/Login/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
>   on line 721
>
> ( ! ) ReflectionException: Class login\Http\Kernel does not exist in 
>   /home/vagrant/Login/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
>   on line 721

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: `Login` and `login` are not the same thing. Make sure you're using the same casing everywhere.

Comment: is there any way to set app name to default?   because I tried to change the case but still not working.

Comment: Sure, revert the change in your version control software. Or you can likely do `php artisan app:name App`.

Comment: Now I am getting this error when I run above command to set it back.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class login\Console\Kernel does not exist in /home/vagrant/Login/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:721

Stack trace:#0 home/vagrant/Login/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(721): ReflectionClass->__construct('login\\Console\\K...')

Comment: OK, now you're in "revert the change" territory.

Comment: is there any command for that?

Comment: Depends which version control software you're using. If you're not using any, I hope you haven't spent too long on the project, or it'll be a whole bunch of find/replace.

Comment: I am not using any version control software but this is the task that I have to submit to the client as core.  And at the last stage I run above command and then refresh the browser and got this issue.

Comment: *Start* using version control software, immediately. You're probably going to have to go through each file and find lines that start with `use login` and switch them back to `use App`.

Comment: "composer dump-autoload"   This command helped me.  Thanks buddy for your help.